# Java output error

Tags: java, output

I can't get this to work properly. It functions as it is supposed to, and does the math, but then it loops once, and ends. I need it to either loop until the users decides to end it, or only run once.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class java {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the simple Calculator program");
    System.out.println("Please type what type of math you would like to do: ");
    System.out.println("1=Addition");
    System.out.println("2=Subtraction");
    System.out.println("3=Multiplication");
    System.out.println("4=Division");
    System.out.println("5=Sqrt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int math = input.nextInt();
    if (math == 1) {
      Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
      int a1;
      int a2;
      int asum;
      System.out.print("Please enter the first number:  ");
      a1 = a.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Please enter the second number:  ");
      a2 = a.nextInt();

      asum = a2 + a1;
      System.out.print("The sum is: " + asum + "Thank You for using this program");
    }

    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int sum;
    System.out.print("Enter first number:  ");
    number1 = number.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Second number:  ");
    number2 = number.nextInt();

    sum = number1 + number2;

    System.out.printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth do you reopen a `Scanner` for each token you are parsing?

Comment: @user1644742, you need to begin with some more simple, make a loop while(inp != 'q') for example, inside de loop read in var inp with a Scanner(only one) and print the input, you will see when a == 'q' the application will end, in other case will be iterating forever.

Answer (score 1):

It is working as it should.
If you want it to loop as per some user input,you must use any looping construct like while.
Instead of `if (math == 1)` use

```
`while (math != exit)`
```

Make a new entry for exit like 0

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
   do{
      // do something.
   } while(some condition);
```

And reapeat the same scanner to get input. You can also add one more option to your menu for repeating and evaluate that with while condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `while` loop. Give the user an option to quit the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class java
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the simple Calculator program");
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Please type what type of math you would like to do: ");
            System.out.println("1=Addition");
            System.out.println("2=Subtraction");
            System.out.println("3=Multiplication");
            System.out.println("4=Division");
            System.out.println("5=Sqrt");
            System.out.println("6=Quit"); // added an option to quit the program
            int math = a.nextInt();
            if (math == 1)
            {
                int a1,a2,asum;
                System.out.print("Please enter the first number:  ");
                a1 = a.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Please enter the second number:  ");
                a2 = a.nextInt();
                asum = a2 + a1;
                System.out.println("The sum is: " + asum + "Thank You for using this program");
            }

            // Include actions for math = 2 to 5

            if(math == 6)
            {
                System.out.println("Thank You for using this program");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The options are displayed again and again after each calculation until the user wants to exit the program by entering `6`.
If you want the program to run only once, you should leave out the outer `while` loop. Everything else remains the same.
PS - You don't need to reopen `Scanner` again and again (at least not in this problem).

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are only reading the input from the console once..you need to keep the console up with something like `while(true) {}` or monitor the console for an exit conditon like    `(" 0 = exit ")` .

Also, I don''t think you will need to read two numbers again and again like you are doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use a do-while loop with a condition till which you wish to execute.

2) Use a switch case and perform the math operations inside the switch case with different operators. As of now you are trying to perform only addition. So you a switch case where you can perform all the operations.

3) In the switch case have an option which calls the exit(0) method. So that you can run the program until the user wish to exit.

4) By using a switch case you can make the user to choose his own option.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire program is correct dude.

Just add

System.exit(0);

In every if(math==1) ,if(math==2)...before their statement ending.

like if(math==1)

{

...

System.exit(0);

}

You can fix your error...

Like me if your error is fixed. If not tell me the error